# Power BI возможно ли показывать в диаграмме категории без объектов по дням?

Tags: диаграммы, powerbi

Есть таблица продаж с объектами и категориями. На диаграмме нужно показать все дни каждого месяца, но ежедневно продаётся не каждый объект,не понимаю, как правильно настроить  диаграмму. Использую календарь как справочник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.в тех строках, где размещаются  даты, есть возможность  выбрать "Показывать элементы без данных"
2.также можно использовать меру ( в условии)

```
    if(isblank(мера), 0, мера)
```